# Running Portal Installer in Windows 7 Windows XP Mode

Tags: websphere-portal

I have just upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 7 and am trying to install IBM Portal Server version 6.0. It doesn't look to be runnable on Windows 7 because I get an operating system pre-requsitie check error.

So as a result I have Portal running in a Windows XP VM but when I go to run install.bat I get an installer that does not show anything.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things that could go wrong here based on the description given, but these should be kept in mind

- From your listed packages it seems like you are missing one of them (W-2).
- Support for running WebSphere Portal in a virtual machine was not introduced until version WebSphere Portal version 6.1
- What is your Windows XP service pack level? SP1 or later are supported

And some other points that you hopefully are familiar with is that Windows XP is no longer supported since some months back and WebSphere Portal 6.0 has not been supported for years (even version 6.1 is hitting end of support about now).

Comment: my company still uses that old version of Portal server so I need to be able to run it. But it doesn't seem to run on windows 7 and since we are not using xp now does that mean I'm stuffed?

Comment: It should work on XP, and I know that I have had it installed on a virtual machine for a development environment. Did you check the service pack level on your XP installation and did you get the missing installation file?

Comment: Hi Daniel. I'm a bit confused about your last comment. In the answer you have said that virtualisation support was not until Portal 6.1 but then in your last comment you are saying that it should work on XP and you got it working. Could you clarify please ? To asnwer your question about the missing disk I've never been asked for W-2 but I do have it ((W-2)WebSphere Portal V6.0 and Workplace Web Content Management V6.0 - WebSphere Process Server).

Comment: Bad wording, should is a overstatement. There was no official virtualisation support for WebSphere Portal 6.0, but I know that I have got it to work once. This does not mean however that it will work for everyone.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind, how exactly are you installing the portal? Are you running the setup directly from the portal installation launcher or are you running through the RAD installer (WebSphere Portal Server test environment installation)?

Comment: ah ok...I am running the installer using the Portal install.bat. I didn't know you could do it using RAD. I'm going to try that now

Comment: Sorry to ask. But how do I install it through RAD?

Comment: If I remember correctly you could start the RAD installation directly, but also through the launchpad and from there you could install the portal test environment, but this depends on RAD version and you would need a RAD that supports portal 6.0. Just remembered one more thing. When you start the portal installation, do you have multiple launch files (such as one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit machines)?

Comment: thanks for your help. I found the launchpad and tried to install Portal but I have the same issue as originally posted. No good.